# AngularJS ui-router: how can I have a fixed header with changing content?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a page where I have a fixed header and changing content, but the fixed header depends on the state route, I would also like the header and the content to have different controllers and templates.

For example for the URL

/user/:userId/profile

I would like the header to display the user name, so it needs to know the value of :userId.

I can achieve this by used named views and ui-router, but here us code duplication that I want to avoid

```js
$stateProvider
            .state('profile', {
                url: '/user/:user_id/profile',
                views: {
                    'header': {
                        templateUrl: 'user-header.html',
                        controller: 'HeaderController'
                    },
                    'info': {
                        templateUrl: 'profile.html',
                        controller: 'ProfileController'
                    }
                }
            }) 
            .state('friends', {
                url: '/user/:user_id/friends',
                views: {
                    'header': {
                        templateUrl: 'user-header.html',
                        controller: 'HeaderController'
                    },
                    'info': {
                        templateUrl: 'friends.html',
                        controller: 'FriendsController'
                    }
                }
            })
```

```html
<section id="startup-header" ui-view="header">

</section>

<section ui-view="info">

</section>
```

How can I define the header once, but have the content defined per content type.

I hope I formulate the questions in a way it's clear what I want to achieve.

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Let's try this:

You can create a parent page with your header for user's profile that will be contain nested child pages:

```
<div id="header">
    <a ui-sref="userPage.profile">Profile</a>
    <a ui-sref="userPage.friends">Friends</a>
    ......
</div>

<div ui-view>

</div>
```

Read more about `ui-sref` ditective [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

And in `$stateProvider` something like:

```
$stateProvider.state('userPage.profile', {
            url: '/user/:user_id/profile',
            templateUrl: 'profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController'
        }
    }).state('friends', {
            url: '/user/:user_id/friends',
            templateUrl: 'friends.html',
            controller: 'FriendsController'
        }
    })
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem as I require the header to also have a controller